How to convert From Raw MYSQL Query to Laravel 10 Query Builder with use index(some_column)
I wanted to convert my Cakephp to Laravel 10.
Here in Cakephp 2.x
$sql = [
    'fields' => [
        'Student.name',
        'Room.id'
    ],
    'joins' => [
        'use index(course)',
        [
            'table' => 'rooms',
            'alias' => 'Room use index(weekday, semester, year)',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => 'Student.course = Room.course'
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        'Student.course IN' => $courses,
        'Room.weekday' => $weekday,
        'Room.semester' => $semester,
        'Room.year' => $year,
    ]
];
$result = $this->Student->find('all', $sql);

then this is now the raw query.
"SELECT 
    Student.name, 
    Room.id 
FROM 
    students AS Student USE INDEX (course)
LEFT JOIN 
    rooms AS Room USE INDEX (weekday, semester, year)
ON 
    Student.course = Room.course 
WHERE 
    Room.weekday = '$day' 
    AND Room.semester = '$semester' 
    AND Room.year = '$year' 
    AND Student.course IN ($implodedCourse);"

After converting it to Laravel 10 I got an error. Here is my code.
$result = DB::table('students as Student use index(course)')
    ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')
    ->join('rooms as Room use index(weekday, semester, year)', function($courseJoin){
    $courseJoin->on('Student.course', '=', 'Room.course'); })
    ->whereIn('Student.course', $courses)
    ->where('Room.weekday', $day)
    ->where('Room.semester', $semester)
    ->where('Room.year', $year);

Error Stated this.
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: Student.name
select "Student"."name", "Room"."id" from "students" as "Student use index(course)" inner join "rooms" as "Room use index(weekday, semester, year)" on "Student"."course" = "Room"."course" where "Student"."course" in (1, 3) and "Room"."weekday" = 3 and "Room"."semester" = 1 and "Room"."year" = 2024

Please help me. Thanks in advance.
Solved... Query Referrence here

I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.

The main issue here is that Laravel wasn't able to understand the use index() in your code.
For Laravel 9 and above, 3 new methods useIndex, forceIndex and ignoreIndex were introduced to the Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder that allows adding index hints.
$result = DB::table('students as Student')
    ->useIndex('course')
    ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('rooms as `Room` use index(weekday, semester, year)'), function ($courseJoin) {
        $courseJoin->on('Student.course', '=', 'Room.course');;
    })
    ->whereIn('Student.course', $courses)
    ->where('Room.weekday', $day)
    ->where('Room.semester', $semester)
    ->where('Room.year', $year)
    ->get();

You'll need to use DB::raw() for adding index hints on joins though
For Laravel < 9, use DB::raw() in the table() method
$result = DB::table(DB::raw('students as `Student` use INDEX(course)'))
    ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('rooms as `Room` use index(weekday, semester, year)'), function ($courseJoin) {
        $courseJoin->on('Student.course', '=', 'Room.course');;
    })
    ->whereIn('Student.course', [1, 2])
    ->where('Room.weekday', 2)
    ->where('Room.semester', 3)
    ->where('Room.year', 2024)
    ->get();


I'll try this when I got back to work. I took the leave on Monday

Hello sir @arun-a-s I tried your solution but I got an error saying
Illuminate\ Database\ QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "use": syntax error
select "Student"."name", "Room"."id" from students as Student use INDEX(course) left join rooms as Room use index(weekday, semester, year) on "Student"."course" = "Room"."course" where "Student"."course" in (1, 3) and "Room"."weekday" = 3 and "Room"."semester" = 1 and "Room"."year" = 2024

$result = DB::table('students as Student')                 ->useIndex('course')                 ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')                 ->leftJoin(DB::raw('rooms as Room USE INDEX (weekday, semester, year)'), function($courseJoin) {                     $courseJoin->on('Student.course', '=', 'Room.course');                 })                 ->whereIn('Student.course', $courses)                 ->where('Room.weekday', $day)                 ->where('Room.semester', $semester)                 ->where('Room.year', $year)                 ->toRawSql();
thank you sir...

I assume two tables mentioned in the query correctly named as students & rooms.
Try this.
$results = DB::table('students as Student')
    ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')
    ->join('rooms as Room', 'Student.course', '=', 'Room.course')
    ->whereIn('Student.course', $courses)
    ->where('Room.weekday', $day)
    ->where('Room.semester', $semester)
    ->where('Room.year', $year)
    ->get();

In whereIn clause you can also specify data instead of $courses as an array format like this-> [1,2,3].
implement this.i think it will work.If not then let me know.
N:B :- remember to import DB facade to the top of the script by using
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;.
In case you need to use index(some_columns) in the query try this.
$result = DB::table(DB::raw('students as Student USE INDEX(course)'))
    ->select('Student.name', 'Room.id')
    ->join(DB::raw('rooms as Room USE INDEX(weekday, semester, year)'), function($courseJoin) {
        $courseJoin->on('Student.course', '=', 'Room.course');
    })
    ->whereIn('Student.course', $courses)
    ->where('Room.weekday', $day)
    ->where('Room.semester', $semester)
    ->where('Room.year', $year)
    ->get();

Check this solution also and let me know.

I tried your implementation sir, it's good
here is the sql log when I use ->toSql()
select "Student"."name", "Room"."id" from "students" as "Student" inner join "rooms" as "Room" on "Student"."course" = "Room"."course" where "Student"."course" in (?, ?) and "Room"."weekday" = ? and "Room"."semester" = ? and "Room"."year" = ?
However it needs to use index(some_columns) after the alias or "AS NewTableName".

@トロイ,I have edited my answer for index(some_columns) .Please check and let me know.

hello sir @Subha, I tried your solution but I still get an error.
Illuminate\ Database\ QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "USE": syntax error
select "Student"."name", "Room"."id" from students as Student USE INDEX(course) inner join rooms as Room USE INDEX(weekday, semester, year) on "Student"."course" = "Room"."course" where "Student"."course" in (1, 3) and "Room"."weekday" = 3 and "Room"."semester" = 1 and "Room"."year" = 2024

@トロイ, Try with this  DB::raw('students USE INDEX (course) as Student') & (DB::raw('rooms USE INDEX (weekday, semester, year) as Room').use this in the existing query keeping remaining query same and let me know. it should be working but don't know why it is not. some issue with USE INDEX.

Thank you sir @Subha I got the query logs right.
select Student.name, Room.id from students as Student use index (course) left join rooms as Room USE INDEX (weekday, semester, year) on Student.course = Room.course where Student.course in (1, 3) and Room.weekday = 2 and Room.semester = 2 and Room.year = 2024
USE INDEX is appearing when I used the MySQL database however it can't be shown in sqlite... Much appreciated sir.

@トロイ, I am glad to help you.Please accept my answer.

@トロイ, I just checked @Arun A S answer. It is more detailed and concise. Thanks for upvoting my answer.But I think you should accept Arun's answer instead of mine.
